# Where can I find the default TCP connection keep alive timeout values for Chrome?

Tags: sockets, google-chrome, tcp

From this URL [HTTP Keep Alive connection timeouts](https://blog.fastmail.com/2011/06/28/http-keep-alive-connection-timeouts/) it says Chrome 13 has at least a 300 second connection timeout. That is if a request to the same server is not made within that timeout the connection will be closed. It also says that every 45 seconds Chrome will send a TCP keep-alive packet until the 300 second timeout expires. This is to avoid NAT/firewall that start dropping connections earlier.

Is there any settings in Chrome that I can check to verify these values? Can anyone point me to any documentation on what the values are on the latest version of Chrome?

Comment: that is a really outdated site. I would not rely on anything.
I am also looking at that myself